# PHP - Find all paths within array (2 sides)

Tags: php, graph, nodes, graph-algorithm

I have a huge array in php (~800 sub arrays):

```
$arrayx = array(

[0] => array("side1" => "XTSWS", "side2" => "WRXXC", "value" => "150"),
[1] => array("side1" => "WRXXC", "side2" => "TXXBD", "value" => "110"),
[2] => array("side1" => "XTSWS", "side2" => "GVFDS", "value" => "40"),
[3] => array("side1" => "XTSWS", "side2" => "ABNMDA", "value" => "1350"),
[4] => array("side1" => "TTTSY", "side2" => "WRXXC", "value" => "1150"),
[5] => array("side1" => "WDWDD", "side2" => "KGADSD", "value" => "10050"),
[6] => array("side1" => "ZZSJH", "side2" => "PPPEIJD", "value" => "1750"),

... 800
);
```

for the sides, i'm trying to find all possible paths from one value to another e.g:

XTSWS -> WRXXC

XTSWS -> TXXBD -> WRXXC

XTSWS -> TXXBD -> ZZSJH -> WRXXC

Is there any efficient way to do this in PHP? I found some examples using graph/nodes in Python etc..

```
$values = $this->findAllPaths("XTSWS", "WRXXC");

function findAllPaths($from, $to)
{

}
```

Comment: can you please what you have written and tell us what we should understand about how you are creating those paths??

Comment: @Berto99 - my question is how to create those paths from the array

Comment: yes but which path?! what's your definition of path? how we should interpretate those datas??

Comment: I think the question is how do I solve travelling salesman problem in PHP?

Comment: So, your big array contains connections between vertex and their weight, right? And you are trying to solve travelling salesman in PHP, right? THe thing is: you haven't actually tried to implement it in your function. Go give it a try, it is well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement backtracking in PHP, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-algorithms/

Since you have 800 elements, it would be wise to use a [stack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-stack.php) on your own instead of relying on recursivity. You will need to somehow ["color"](https://study.com/academy/lesson/coloring-traversing-graphs-in-discrete-math.html) the items that are already traversed on any current position and uncolor them when you backtrack, so you will avoid cycles.

This will never be very efficient, because you are backtracking, which has exponential complexity and you do not have any option to do this differently, because you need to find all paths.